# Can I use Azure authentication to get access to a users consumption data via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

Currently, a user has to add my application within the Azure portal. I will then get a ClientID etc. and use that to get access to the users Consumption data. I wondered if I could streamline this process by asking for consent using the Azure authentication.

Pre-thanks!

**
Let me elaborate a bit more, I'm creating an application that will help the user by giving insights on there cloud spend. I get the data using the consumption API. At the moment I get access to that API by them giving my app credentials via the Azure portal. But I want to get the access via Azure authentication
**

Comment: Do you mean list users with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me elaborate a bit more, I'm creating an application that will help the user by giving insights on there cloud spend. I get the data using the consumption API. At the moment I get access to that API by them giving my app credentials via the Azure portal. But I want to get the access via Azure authentication

Answer (score 1):

In Azure AD, there are several auth flows, not sure which one you want to use. Generally, these flows can be divided into two types, user-interactive or non-interactive.

Per my understanding, you want to call the [Azure Consumption REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/) via Azure AD auth. If you want the user-interactive way, you could use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#authorization-code-grant-interactive-clients). If you want a non-interactive way, you could use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#client-credentials-grant-non-interactive-clients).

For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: This is what I needed, Thanks!